# WHERE clause doesn't seem to work in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The query `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id LIKE '%1%` is not working properly, it's not select the id 1.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root' , ''); 
mysql_select_db('database'); 
$sql = ("select * from search WHERE id LIKE '%3%'"); 
mysql_query($sql); 
$my_variable = mysql_query($sql);  
$display_data = mysql_fetch_row($my_variable); 

   while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_variable)) { 
        $id = $list['id']; 
        $title = $list['title']; 
        $keywords = $list['keywords'];
        $img = $list['img'];
        $link = $list['link'];
   }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Its selecting another id and not the id that I give

Comment: I dont get an error...Its just select select only id 1-9 and its not selecting the correct id...

Comment: your code will select any id that has the digit 3 in it. 3, 13, 23, 3451, etc

Comment: When writing a question, please always explain what is wrong, and not just that it doesn't work.

Comment: andrew...can you help select only the 3 or that I want please

Comment: fyi, mysql functions are deprecated, use mysqli or PDO

Comment: @halfer sorry, when I noticed it was already too late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) of `mysql_fetch_row` it

> Returns a numerical array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

Which means that the first result won't show up in the next (`mysql_fetch_assoc`) procedure. You could try removing the `$display_data = mysql_fetch_row($my_variable);` line and only use the `while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($my_variable)) { ... }` procedure. See if that solves your problem.

Comment: Why would it return no results the second time?

Comment: Its not the problem ;/ Its not selecting the correct ID..or title with spacing

Comment: I see that you want to ONLY get the record containing ID 1? * looking at your question *. Why not use `id = 1` instead of `id LIKE '%1%'?

Comment: Robin its not working ;/ I dont know why I have tried anything

Comment: @I'mNoob I have updated my answer according to information found on PHP.net

Comment: Yeah its not working -_- pfff..not displaying..dat problem idk why

Comment: @I'mNoob Can you try to run the query using - for example - phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench? Check if your query return records there so you're sure that they exist.

Comment: Thank you :D That was the problem thanks thanks thanks!!!! :D You are amazing ^_^

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to SELECT id 1 then use = not LIKE.  The way LIKE is being used it will match every id that has a 1 in it and you are not guaranteed to get the first one in order, so instead use:

SELECT * FROM search WHERE id = 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = ("select * from search WHERE id ='3'");
```

The id is an integer use `=` instead of `like` . Equal is more accurate.

Comment: If it's an integer, `= 3` would be more correct (no quotes). But +1 anyway.

Comment: Its not selecting anything..;/

Comment: But quotes is always an safer option whether its integer or string... :)

Answer (score 0):

And first echo your query in your program->

```
echo $sql;die;
```

copy that query and run it on your `phpmyadmin`
and then check is your `column id` is `int type` if it is then like will not give you the result. You have to use the `where clause` here .But if you have the `column id` is of `type varchar` then definitely give you the result .
Try to use **search tab under your database->table in your phpmyadmin** and put the condition there.
You will definitely get your answer there.

Comment: I try it before you send it...On phpmyadmin its working and displaying that I want..but on the web is not working displaying that I said to display...

Comment: did u try to put the same phpmyadmin running query into your $sql varialbe->$sql = "write your phpmyadmin running query here as it is"; then run the script.